# How to exchange columns of a matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

I am trying to exchange the columns of a matrix in Python the column with the smallest prime with the column with the bigger prime of the given matrix

I was trying

```
def swapcol(matriz,col1,col2):
    for i in range(len(matriz)):
        aux = matriz[i][col1]
        matriz[i][col1] = matriz[i][col2]
        matriz[i][col2] = aux
    


def esprimo(n):
    m = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            m += 1
    if m == 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def leermatrix(matrix,r,c):
    for i in range(r):
        a = []
        for j in range(c):
            a.append(int(input("enter element: ")))
        matrix.append(a)

r = int(input("enter the number of rows: "))
c = int(input("enter the number of columns: "))
matrix = []


leermatrix(matrix,r,c)

mayp = matrix[0][0]
menp = matrix[0][0]
colmen = 0
colmay = 0

for j in range(c):
    for i in range(r):
        if esprimo(matrix[i][j]) and matrix[i][j] > mayp:
            mayp = matrix[i][j]
            colmay = j
        if esprimo(matrix[i][j]) and esprimo(matrix[i][j]) < menp:
            menp = matrix[i][j]
            colmen = j



swapcol(matrix,colmay,colmen)
print(matrix)
```

the output I get is the same matrix that I put, what did I get wrong?

Comment: Which input did you enter and which output did you expect?

Comment: @MariaK I input[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] and get [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]  but I was expecting [[2,1,3],[5,4,6],[8,7,9]]

Comment: You shouldn't be setting initial values of `mayp` and `menp` as the first element of the matrix. If the first element is the smallest (or largest), value of menp (or mayp) will never change, irrespective of if the value is a prime or not. This is what's happening when you set menp = matrix[0][0] since its value is 1 which is the smallest

Comment: @Chhaganlaal I put 0 as the value of mayp and menp and still did not workout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few modifications to your code.

- The condition `esprimo(matrix[i][j]) and matrix[i][j] > mayp:` should be replaced with `matrix[i][j] > mayp`
- The condition `esprimo(matrix[i][j]) and esprimo(matrix[i][j]) < menp` should be replaced with `matrix[i][j] < menp and matrix[i][j] > 1`
- Initialized `mayp` with `-1` and `menp` with `positive infinity` to ensure they are updated correctly.
- Also there's no need to swap columns if the `colmay` and `colmen` values are the same

##### Here's your solution:

```
def swapcol(matriz, col1, col2):
    for i in range(len(matriz)):
        aux = matriz[i][col1]
        matriz[i][col1] = matriz[i][col2]
        matriz[i][col2] = aux
    return matriz

def esprimo(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def leermatrix(matrix, r, c):
    for i in range(r):
        a = []
        for j in range(c):
            a.append(int(input("Enter element: ")))
        matrix.append(a)

r = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
c = int(input("Enter the number of columns: "))
matrix = []

leermatrix(matrix, r, c)

print("Original matrix:")
for row in matrix:
    print(row)


mayp = -1
menp = float('inf')
colmen = 0
colmay = 0

for j in range(c):
    for i in range(r):
        if esprimo(matrix[i][j]):
            if matrix[i][j] > mayp:
                mayp = matrix[i][j]
                colmay = j
            if matrix[i][j] < menp and matrix[i][j] > 1:
                menp = matrix[i][j]
                colmen = j

if colmay != colmen:
    matriz = swapcol(matrix, colmay, colmen)

print("\nMatrix after swapping columns:")
for row in matriz:
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
Original matrix:
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]

Matrix after swapping columns:
[2, 1, 3]
[5, 4, 6]
[8, 7, 9]
```